# how to add react responsive carousel swipe animation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using next JS with tailwind css and using `react-responsive-carousel` package.the issue that i'm having is that when i start to swipe the images they're next to each other horizontally. they have no effect (like fade or ease in out) to them while swiping. and i wanted to make animation transition with ease-in-out or fade to it. how can i add fade in out animation instead of its default slide?

```
<Carousel
        swipeScrollTolerance={100}
        preventMovementUntilSwipeScrollTolerance
        key={house.id}
        axis="horizontal"
        showStatus={false}
        showThumbs={false}
        swipeable={true}
        className="group "
        renderIndicator={(onClickHandler, isSelected, index, label) => {
          const defStyle = {
            marginLeft: 6,
            color: "#b9b9b9",
            cursor: "pointer",
          };
          const style = isSelected
            ? { ...defStyle, color: "#dcdcdc" }
            : { ...defStyle };
          return (
            <span
              style={style}
              onClick={onClickHandler}
              onKeyDown={onClickHandler}
              value={index}
              key={index}
              role="button"
              tabIndex={0}
              aria-label={`${label} ${index + 1}`}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faCircle}
                className="sm:h-[0.35rem] sm:w-[0.35rem] h-2 w-2 font-thin"
              />
            </span>
          );
        }}
        renderArrowPrev={(clickHandler, hasPrev) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={`${
                hasPrev && !toggle ? "absolute" : "hidden"
              } top-0 bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center items-center p-3 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer z-10 text-white`}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faChevronCircleLeft}
                className="h-8 w-8 font-thin"
              />
            </div>
          );
        }}
        renderArrowNext={(clickHandler, hasNext) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={`${
                hasNext && !toggle ? "absolute" : "hidden"
              } top-0 bottom-0 right-0 flex justify-center items-center p-3 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointerz-10 text-white`}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faChevronCircleRight}
                className="h-8 w-8 font-thin"
              />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      >
        {house.img.map((img, index) => {
          return (
            <Link href={`/living/${house.id}`} key={img.id}>
              <div
                key={img.id}
                className=" w-full relative -z-10 pt-[100%] cursor-pointer"
              >
                <Image
                  src={img.img}
                  alt="profile"
                  fill
                  className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 -z-10 object-cover rounded-2xl ease-in-out duration-200"
                />
              </div>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the carousel uses the traditional 'slide' style animation.
> There is also a built in fade animation, which can be used by passing
> 'fade' to the animationHandler prop. *note: the 'fade' animation does
> not support swiping animations, so you may want to set swipeable to
> false

Example of fade animation is available here
http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/storybook/?path=/story/01-basic--fade

Hope, This answers your Question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33984871)